# Failed to load API definition 500 Internal Server Error with Swagger

Tags: swagger

I created a brand new Asp.net Core 2.2 web api app. 
Then I configured Swagger as follows.
In the ConfigureServices method of the startup file I have the following.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
    {
        Title = "My API", Version = "v1" 
    });
});

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Next in the Configure method, I have,

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
else
    app.UseHsts();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMvc();

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

So far so good. Swagger UI is working Awesome.
Problems started when I introduced a simple MVC controller.

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I get the following error

Failed to load API definition Errors Fetch error Internal Server Error /swagger/v1/swagger.json

[image: Swagger Error with Asp.net Mvc Core Controller]

Seems that Swagger is not accepting Asp.net core mvc controller. If I comment out that mvc controller, things work fine again.

Is there a way out of this.

Comment: Do consider this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56914161/9412240) hopefully this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try to decorate your method in controller with http verb notation:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet, Route("myRoute")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Just the [HttpGet] notation method should solve the problem, if you dont want to put the route.

Answer (score 3):

Your docs are not imported.

Assume your project is *github.com/deepaksinghvi/catalogwf* and docs folder is is inside it.

try importing your docs as follows and it would work

```
_ "github.com/deepaksinghvi/catalogwf/docs"
```